# How to change speed of segue between ViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, segue, uistoryboard

Is it possible to control segue speed?

I have checked the documentation but there is no given method by Apple.

But I am more looking for ideas to hack in and change lower level code to make segueing in **slow motion**.

Comment: Is this for debugging or for actual production? The former can be solved within the simulator by using Debug->Toggle Slow Animations.

Comment: @Till, I am looking for actual production. Other ways is to create a full screen overlay and give the effect of segueing but it doesn't work very well.

Comment: Have you looked into custom segues? You can subclass UIStoryboardSegue object and implement the -perform method where you can create your own animation, complete with duration.

Comment: @JasonC.Howlin Your comment is as good as an answer :)

Comment: @JasonC.Howlin, I will look into it, Do you mind making it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks Mate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below code is of custom segue, and you can set **duration** of transition in code.

```
- (void)perform 
{
    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;
    [UIView transitionFromView:src.view
                        toView:dst.view
                      duration:3.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    completion:NULL];

}
```

Sample project is here in GitHub:https://github.com/weed/p120805_CustomSegue

You can download and just run it. I wish this is help for you.

Answer (score 0):

to prevent zombies creation i think better to do use subview add/remove as well:

```
- (void)perform
{
    UIView *src = ((UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController).view;
    UIView *dst = ((UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController).view;

    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    [window insertSubview:dst aboveSubview:src];

    [UIView transitionFromView:src
                        toView:dst
                      duration:1.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        [src removeFromSuperview];
                        window.rootViewController = self.destinationViewController;
                    }];
}
```

this is if you are not using navigation controller!