# Changing duration of segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm using `performSegueWithIdentifier`. 
How can I change the duration (in seconds) of the the transition animation?
What's the easiest / best way?
Edit: Tutorial solved problem.

Comment: You need to make a custom `segue animation`. Take a look at [this](https://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/) tutorial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change speed of segue between ViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813121/how-to-change-speed-of-segue-between-viewcontrollers)